# Puppet server cannot find certificate request when importing certificate

Tags: installation, server, puppet

I am trying to install puppet server and client in two Ubuntu 10.04. one Ubuntu server which has puppet master and Ubuntu client which has puppet client.

```
**I referred the below link for installation**
```

[installing and configuring puppet](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/puppet.html)

I dont have a DNS server so i had added host entry in both server and client.

When i am importing certificate

sudo puppetca --sign meercat02.example.com

i am getting error

err could not call sign could not find certificate request

Comment: Deepak, you said you're doing this on 10.04, but the guide you posted is for 11.04. Which one do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deepak, you need to replace 'meercat02.example.com' with your actual host name.

You can get a list of the certificates waiting to be signed with

```
puppet cert --list
```

On the puppet master. You should see your puppet client listed there and you can then run

```
sudo puppetca --sign whatever.your.hostname.is
```

If you don't see the client's hostname, then you may want to verify that the hosts entries you created are correct.